# Converting strings to numbers before Adding

Tags: javascript

JSLint says the `+` are getting confused in the hints in Webstorm yet this code works.

```
var totalheightInInches = +selectedFeetToInches + +this.inchSelect.get("value");
```

is this bad practice or is there a better way to convert so that JSLint is satisfied since JSLint is based on best practices as we know?

before people hastily reach to close this, I wanna know what's some of the better ways to handle this conversion.

Comment: That's a shortcut for using `Number(num)` and should be valid in my opinion. The other option(s) are `parseFloat` and `parseInt`. Note that `+` will return `NaN` if the string isn't a valid number in any way, while `parseFloat`/`parseInt` will ignore any invalid trailing characters in the string (and outside of that, return `NaN` if the string isn't a valid number)

Comment: yea I like the short +, much more readable, meaning less text is more readable to me in any language

Comment: JSLint is just one person's idea of how javascript should be written. there is nothing wrong with the code you've posted. "Best practice" is just a buzz phrase.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict I agree, and I tend to use `+` almost all the time when I want to convert any string to a number

Answer (score 2):

You can use the parseFloat and parseInt functions

```
parseFloat("2", 10) //returns the Number 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that `+`  is preferred in this case, since it explicitly casts the operand to Number. It is equivalent to `Number(x)` but less to type. `parseInt` and `parseFloat` are meant for trimming trailing non–number characters (e.g. converting `5px` to `5` or `5.5cm` to `5.5`) and infer that you want an integer or float, `+` doesn't.

And did I say it's less to type? :-)

The production +*identifier* + +*identifier* can only be interpreted one way, it's not ambiguous.

Comment: +1 True, that is totally a good way of doing it. The + +identifier looks ugly, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder, and this is programming, not composition. It's the fastest way of doing it in cases where it's not going to be used in part of a formula later (in which case subtraction can be used and then the entire result can be negated in one step by reversing part of the formula, for instance by writing y1-y2 instead of y2-y1).

Answer (score 1):

If you are merely trying to use a number which has unfortunately been stored as a string, then parseInt() and parseFloat() are like killing a fly with an atomic bomb. They are intended for much heavier work like extracting the numeric portion of strings while doing optional base conversions, etc. JavaScript is a dynamically typed language which automatically decides whether data is a number or a string. As you know by your question, "+" is one of the cases when this dynamically-typed goodness is not always such a nice thing.

If you have a numeric value which is unfortunately stored as a string, then we can note and take advantage of what JavaScript does internally (as per the ECMA standard), which for "+" is ambiguously trying to guess whether addition or concatenation is intended, but for subtraction always means interpreting all variables as numeric data types or NaN (just like the suggested conversion functions do as a small part of their job).

So I don't see any point in slowing down my code with `parseInt()` unless I actually want to parse an integer from another string to do base conversion. That would be like using `Boolean()` inside of every if statement to convert every expression to a Boolean value.

For the deep internals of my programs, I use subtraction exclusively for adding any variable that sometimes might be stored as a string, and in every formula depending on the result I simply replace the result variable with the opposite of it. The result is zero extra code and maximum execution efficiency, at the cost of confusion (the confusion goes away as soon as anyone recognizes this practice).

For more human readable code, while still much faster than using either of the parsing functions, I subtract 0 with a comment mentioning that I do so to ensure the unspecified type of data will be understood to be a number.

(And actually, I also do + +variable as well when I am sure that my whitespace isn't going to be collapsed later. That's the only downside to the + + method, because nearly all code can be written without whitespace, but this operation requires either whitespace or parentheses.)

Comment: `And actually, I also do + +variable as well when I am sure that my whitespace isn't going to be collapsed later` - are you talking about with minification? If your minifier messes this up, you shouldn't be using it

Answer (score 0):

do like

```
var totalheightInInches = parseInt(selectedFeetToInches,10) + parseInt(this.inchSelect.get("value"),10);
```

#### update

if you are expecting a floating point value. as [Parthik Gosar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93468/coffeeaddict) suggests `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` would be the best fit.

Comment: Always specify the radix when using parseInt.

Comment: @VimalStan—according to ES there should be no need to, but testing shows there is. :-( ["If radix not present or is undefined the Number 10 is used as the value of radix."](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.2)

Comment: @RobG You shouldn't have to, but getting stuck trying to figure out why "08" gets parsed to 0 is annoying as hell if you don't know what to look for. Just trying to save some developer's hair :)

Comment: @mithunsatheesh what if the string is 1.55...??

Comment: @PrasathK: i have updated my answer. you may use `parseFloat`

Answer (score 0):

The JSLint warning disappeared by adding (). Makes sense.

```
var totalheightInInches = (+selectedFeetToInches) + (+this.inchSelect.get("value"));`
```

Comment: That's good to know, but the truth is that your existing code is perfectly good as is, and is about the shortest possible way of doing what you need to do. JSLint is not the final word and code shouldn't be added to make it happy, unless you have an obnoxious boss that says it is and wants you to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Number()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) function ....

```
Number("100"); // returns 100

var totalheightInInches = Number(selectedFeetToInches) + Number(this.inchSelect.get("value"));
```

Another way to convert , divide or multiply it by 1,,,

```
var totalheightInInches = selectedFeetToInches/1 + this.inchSelect.get("value")/1;
```

Comment: hmm so then what's wrong with just using +?  maybe JSLint is too picky, I don't have to do everything JSLint suggests unless there's a critical reason I need to worry about the + which is why I'm posting, to figure that out.  I know it seems like it could be confusing to the compiler but it's working so maybe alright.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict It could well just be JSLint being picky about what it thinks might be a programming error.

Comment: yea sort of like R#.  thing is I guess my lead wants all JSLint warnings resolved...

Comment: @CoffeAddict If you want it in less words,then divide or multiply it by 1

Comment: @PrasathK I found out why the -1: Number doesn't let you specify a radix to guard against bad input, so [it will always work like parseInt with no radix specified](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp). In Firefox's Firebug console: `parseInt("0x10") == 16` (treated as hexadecimal, bad), `parseInt("010") == 8` (treated as octal, bad), but `parseInt("0x10", 10) == 0` (ok) and `parseInt("010", 10) == 10` (good). That means using `Number(str)` is bad, and one should be using `parseInt(str, 10)` instead.

Comment: @PrasathK You can use `parseFloat("10.55", 10)` if you're expecting floating-point numbers. If the number is an integer, it will return an integer, i.e.: `parseFloat("15", 10)` returns `15`, and not `15.0`.

Comment: @PrasathK `"0x10"/1 == 16` (bad), `"010"/1 == 10` (good). You should just be using `parseInt(str, 10)` or `parseFloat(str, 10)` it seems. It still provides the radix guard, whereas these methods don't.

Comment: Actually, `Number(010) == 10)` (good), but it too gets tripped up on hexadecimal inputs. (By the way, I'm not downvoting)